# Java visual VM пишет cannot find jdk 1.7 or higher

Tags: java, visualvm

На пространстве интернета нашел вот эту [статью](http://devwebcl.blogspot.ru/2014/07/jvm-for-visualvm.html) (на самом деле нашел больше, но все предлагают именно это решение), что надо зайти по пути visualvm_139\etc\
и там отредактировать файл visualvm.conf. Я отредактировал но эффекта ноль,
может кто нибудь подсказать?

Comment: Возможно это из-за 9-го jdk 8-ой без проблем подхватил

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, добавь в visualvm.conf:

```
visualvm_jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1
```

БЕЗ пробелов, БЕЗ кавычек! Путь конечно свой